# Edge flow in animation

Tags: topology

I'm working on a character and was following some of the tutorials Blender has for Rain and Snow. A smooth edge flow is always emphasized but when I get to the pants, they have modeled in cloth folds. The thing about those is, they whack out any smooth edge flow and instead, send the flow in all kinds of directions. In the picture of Snow, I clicked a couple flows, and you can see they go all over. Isn't this a no-no? What will this do to animation later? I'm wondering because I spent a bunch of time modeling in similar folds then sat back and second guessed myself as to whether I was making a mistake or not [image], both of these have the edge flow swirling around the legs [image] it seems that would bring problems come rigging time.

Comment: Yes that's weird but if it doesn't cause any problem when animated...

Comment: It can be a bad idea.  Where the loop bends, the weight gradient probably doesn't; under deformation, this leaves you with a (more) non-planar face where you could see triangulation.  But topology is a balancing act, and, like the pirate code, the rules aren't rules so much as guidelines.

Comment: Yah, even though this topology was done by the Blender team, I had to question it as a smooth edge flow was stressed so much previously. As you click on different flows, you really see a lot of really hard shifts that don't carry on up the leg at all, they shift ankle to knee then right back down to the ankle.  I'm thinking that modeling the folds isn't the best way to go, the diamonds you add create too many edge flow changes. I think I'll just rip them out of mine and find another way to make folds in clothes.